# Optimizar mapeo entidad Entity Framework a Objeto

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Desde una db me estoy obteniendo una entidad Pais que tiene esta estructura:

```
Pais
{
    public int PaisId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ciudade> Ciudades { get; set; }
}
```

Dentro del país se puede ver que hay una lista de Ciudade con la siguiente estructura

```
Ciudade
{
    public int CiudadId { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public bool Estado { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PaisId { get; set; }
}
```

Estas las quiero convertir a un objeto **GetPaisesResponse** con la siguiente estructura:

```
public class GetPaisesResponse
    {
        public List<Pais> Paises { get; set; }

        public GetPaisesResponse()
        {
            this.Paises = new List<Pais>();
        }
    }
```

**Pais**

```
public class Pais
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<Ciudad> Ciudades { get; set; }

        public Pais()
        {
            this.Ciudades = new List<Ciudad>();
        }
    }
```

**Ciudad**

```
public class Ciudad
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es en una API devolver un país con sus ciudades, ya lo tengo hecho de esta manera y funciona bien, pero mi duda es si puedo optimizar el **foreach** que mapea cada ciudad, porque no se que tan performante sería realizar este proceso para muchos paises con muchas ciudades cada uno.

Esta es la forma en la que la estoy haciendo actualmente:

```
GetPaisesResponse response = new GetPaisesResponse();
                using (var db = new AmericaVirtualEntities())
                {
                    var paises = await db.Paises.Where(x => x.Estado).ToListAsync();
                    if (paises != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var pais in paises)
                        {
                            var ciudades = new List<Ciudad>();
                            foreach (var ciudad in pais.Ciudades)
                            {
                                ciudades.Add(new Ciudad
                                {
                                    Id = ciudad.CiudadId,
                                    Nombre = ciudad.Nombre
                                });
                            }
                            response.Paises.Add(new Contracts.Contratos.Pais.Pais
                            {
                                Id = pais.PaisId,
                                Nombre = pais.Nombre,
                                Ciudades = ciudades
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                return response;
```

Comment: Según entiendo tienes dos entidades de la bd que son País y ciudad y lo que quieres es mapear estas entidades a unos DTOs serían?? de País y Ciudad? Si es asi podrias hacerlo de varias formas.. Con AutoMapper que en un paquete de Nugget y tambien podrias haciendo un Extension Method en tus entidades que conviertan la entidad a DTO

Comment: Cuando se trata de explorar opciones que ofrezcan mejor rendimiento, lo mejor es hacer pruebas comparativas. Cada escenario es diferente y lo que funciona bien en unos casos no necesariamente funciona bien en otros.

Answer (score 1):

```
GetPaisesResponse response = new GetPaisesResponse();
using(var db = new AmericaVirtualEntities())
{
    var paises = await db.Paises.Where(x => x.Estado).ToListAsync();
    response.Paises = paises?.ConvertAll(x => new Contracts.Contratos.Pais {
        Id = x.PaisId,
        Nombre = x.Nombre,
        Ciudades = x.Ciudades.ConvertAll(c => new Ciudad {
            Id = c.CiudadId,
            Nombre = c.Nombre
        })
    });
}
return response;
```

Actualmente, es la forma en la que lo manejo. Pero no sé si es lo más óptimo, hay que sacrificar un poco de rendimiento al momento de mapear, y no encuentro una forma más adecuada. Podrías optar por algunos paquetes Nuget.